# JavaScript CSS Modal not displaying correct info

Tags: javascript, html, flask, modal-dialog

So I'm using a Jinja2 Template in Flask to render a HTML document. Im passing a dict named "healthy_alerts" into the Jinja template. The dict snippet looks likes this (sensitive values manipulated):

```
healthy_alerts = {
    ...
    "52.NE": {
        "appliance_id": 123456, 
        "severity": "green", 
        "ip": "x.x.x.x", 
        "hostname": "HG-EDGE-FranceAntony-ECV01", 
        "serial": "11-11-11-11-11", 
        "critical_alarms": 0
    }, 
    "6.NE": {
        "appliance_id": 7891011, 
        "severity": "green", 
        "ip": "y.y.y.y", 
        "hostname": "HG-EDGE-Schiltach-ECV01", 
        "serial": "22-22-22-22-22", 
        "critical_alarms": 0
    }
}
```

This is a code snippet:

```
<div id="alarms" align="center">

    {% if healthy_alerts %}
    <div class="healthy_div">
        {% for dev in healthy_alerts %}
                <button class="btn_healthy" id="{{ healthy_alerts.get(dev).get('hostname') }}Btn"></button>


                <div id="{{ healthy_alerts.get(dev).get('hostname') }}Modal" class="modal">
                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <p>{{ healthy_alerts.get(dev) }}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <script>
                    // Get the modal
                    var modal = document.getElementById('{{ healthy_alerts.get(dev).get("hostname") }}Modal');

                    // Get the button that opens the modal
                    var btn = document.getElementById("{{ healthy_alerts.get(dev).get("hostname") }}Btn");

                    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
                    btn.onclick = function() {
                        modal.style.display = "block";
                    }

                    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                    span.onclick = function() {
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                    }

                    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                    window.onclick = function(event) {
                        if (event.target == modal) {
                            modal.style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

It seems like everything is almost there but the only problem is when I click on any of the modal buttons, it always shows me the same entry ("6.NE").

When I inspect the page in Chrome I can see the correct info is getting populated for all the modals. However, as you can see from the following chrome output, when I click on the the modal button it still always shows the same info (the "6.NE" entry) no matter what.

I think it may be some trivial JavaScript issue but I'm not a JavaScript coder.
[image]

Comment: Please post your **produced** HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Jinja but based on the JavaScript code I'd say it's because you aren't scoping your variables correctly, so they're being treated as globals. The variables `modal`, `button` and `span` aren't declared in a function so they'll be treated as globals despite using `var`. Even though each of your `<script>` tags is separate they still share the same globals. It's only `modal` that is a problem as it's used inside the event handlers and will reference the last value assigned to `modal`.

If you wrap that script code in an IIFE you should be fine:

```
(function() {
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('{{ healthy_alerts.get(dev).get("hostname") }}Modal');

    // ...

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
})();
```

If you aren't familiar with IIFEs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: Many thanks for this, you were absolutely right. I was quite sure it was variable scoping issue but I just wasn't sure how to resolve it. However, one thing that isn't working is the clicking the "x" button or clicking anywhere outside the modal doesn't seem to close the modal, the page gets stuck with the modal. I suspect its a similar issue so I tried to wrap those onclick functions in IIFE but to no avail.

Comment: I abbreviated the code in my example but my intent was for you to wrap the entire lot in a single IIFE. Everything from the opening `<script>` to the closing `</script>` should be inside that one function. If you wrap each bit in its own IIFE then they'll each have separate scopes and won't be able to see each other's variables. That could be made to work but you'd need to copy all those `document.getElementById` lines into each function that needs them.